# Write data from Socket.io to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io, google-cloud-storage

I get audio data from [this](https://github.com/goodatlas/react-native-audio-record) package in my React Native project and I then send the data chunks over socket.io to my Node.js server.

```
AudioRecord.on('data', data => {
        // base64-encoded audio data chunks
        const binary = Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('utf-8')
        socketClient.io.emit('binaryData', binary)
    })
```

The data that my server receives is readable because I send that data through this transform onto a speech recognition service that returns accurate results.

```
const speechAudioInputStreamTransform = new Transform({
    transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
        if (newStream && lastAudioInput.length !== 0) {
            // Approximate math to calculate time of chunks
            const chunkTime = streamingLimit / lastAudioInput.length
            if (chunkTime !== 0) {
                if (bridgingOffset < 0) {
                    bridgingOffset = 0
                }
                if (bridgingOffset > finalRequestEndTime) {
                    bridgingOffset = finalRequestEndTime
                }
                const chunksFromMS = Math.floor(
                    (finalRequestEndTime - bridgingOffset) / chunkTime
                )
                bridgingOffset = Math.floor(
                    (lastAudioInput.length - chunksFromMS) * chunkTime
                )

                for (let i = chunksFromMS; i < lastAudioInput.length; i++) {
                    if (recognizeStream) {
                        recognizeStream.write(lastAudioInput[i])
                    }
                }
            }
            newStream = false
        }

        audioInput.push(chunk)

        if (recognizeStream) {
            recognizeStream.write(chunk)
        }

        callback()
    },
})
```

However when I write this data to Google Cloud Storage the file saves and contains data but seems corrupted as it is unplayable.

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const storage = new Storage(storageOptions)
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)
const file = filename + '.wav'
const storageFile = bucket.file.createWriteStream()

client.on('binaryData', (data) => {
        const buffer = Buffer.from(data)
        if (recognizeStream != null) {
            storageFile.write(buffer)
            speechAudioInputStreamTransform.write(buffer)
        }
    })
```

When the user on the RN side terminates the session, `storageFile.end()` is called.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that the file is actually done writing (nothing left in the buffer) before storageFile.end() is being called? How big are these .wav files?

Comment: Hi @GabeWeiss, I am honestly not sure, don't know how to check if the file is done writing. I call the .end() after the client disconnects. The files range depending on the length of the session but about 3MB for 20 secs I believe. I record the audio at 44100Hz, 16 Bit and 1 channel

Comment: As a test, looks like the file stream you create with `createWriteStream()` has a `finish` event. You could, instead of ending on the client disconnect, end on that event. So `const storageFile = bucket.file.createWriteStream().on('finish', function() { storageFile.end() }` Although I'm not POSITIVE you need that? I haven't worked with it directly so I don't know if finish() will natively call end or not... You might also consider moving the creation of the stream into the `client.on('binaryData')` scope instead of having it global, so you get new file streams each time.

Comment: I tried adding the .on('finish') but it never gets called.

Comment: That's a pretty good clue that you're closing the file stream before it's done writing. ;) Try removing the storageFile.end() call?

Comment: Hi @GabeWeiss I removed the .end() but still the finish event is never called. Do you think it might have something to do with me writing to 2 streams at the same time. Does that have any adverse effects on the write to GCS?

Comment: I don't THINK so? I'm afraid I haven't worked with that API specifically. :( I'll see if I can poke some folks that have to come chime in.